# mysql- How to Update a record only under a specific condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
ID NAME age TIME
1  Mike 23  10
2  Kyle 24  20
```

Name is Unique

sometimes when I want to Insert a new record, I want to replace the old one by a new one not inserting a new record

for example if I have this record:

```
1  Mike 23  10
```

and I want to insert this record :

```
1 Mike2 23 25
```

I replace the older one by the new one:

```
ID NAME age TIME
1  Mike2 23  25
2  Kyle 24  20
```

I do it by `INSET INTO TABLE(NAME) VALUES('newName') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NAME='newName';`

BUT what if I want to replace it only if the newTIME is bigger than the old time, for example:

for example if I have this record:

```
1  Mike 23  10
```

If the new record TIME is 25 we replace the record:

```
1  Mike2 23  25
2  Kyle 24  20
```

If the new record TIME is 2 we don't replace the record:

```
1  Mike 23  10
2  Kyle 24  20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with can put a conditional expression in the `on duplicate key update` clause:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(NAME, time)
    VALUES('newName', time)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
        UPDATE NAME = (case when values(time) > time then values(name) else name end),
               time = (case when values(time) > time then values(time) else time end);
```

Note:  the query in your question doesn't have a `time` in the `insert`, but it is implied by your question.

Comment: Nice, just beat me! I'd change `time` in the VALUES statement, just to make it abundantly clear that it is passed in.

Comment: `> time` means : greater than the `new value` or the `table column name`??

Comment: which time is for use, can you change the example, it's confusing

Comment: @user78050 `> time` is the existing time, you should be able to work that out from the logic. The `time` in the line `VALUES('newName', time)` is where you pass in the time; e.g `VALUES('Mark2',25)`.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it keeps printing, `syntax error near > time`

Comment: @user78050 . . . The syntax basically works in this SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa217.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something more or less along the lines of:

"UPDATE table_name set TIME = newtime where name = 'Mikes' and newtime > TIME"

?